# how to connect ms sql server with aspwebsite project?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

in my project, there're name,surname,e- mail regions.then user must tick to "Okey".if users  entered textboxs correctly, i want to transfer these knowledges to my sql database. how can i do that?(in okey.buton click or textname_text_changed).

Comment: You really need to learn some basics before asking questions, so try reading a book or two :) ...

Comment: i only want logical solution,not code. pls explain shortly.

Comment: (A) read documentation for asp.net (b) follow examples given in there. Good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this sample

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2000032601&page=1